# Simplify vector expression - is there something like "Factor" for vectors, dot products etc.?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

I am looking for a way to simplify dot products etc.

Here is a minimal example: Lets say I have two vectors a and b:

```
Array[a,2]
Array[b,2]
```

Now I evaluate their dot product:

```
c = a.b
```

which should give me something like this

```
a[1]b[1] + a[2]b[2]
```

What I need is a way to transform this expression back into a dot product. So I am looking for a function that realises that I can write this as a.b (similiar to "Factor" for polynomial expressions), e.g.

```
Function[c]
```

should give

```
a.b
```

In a more general context, I would like to display scalars as vector/matrix/tensor expressions, meaning mathematica should also realize that

```
m[1,1] + m[2,2]
```

is simply

```
Tr[m]
```

and display it as such.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you realize that there is no unique inverse for a dot product? There are infinitely many dot products that give the same result. See, for instance, this one: `{a1, a2}.{b1 + c/a1, b2 - c/a2} // Simplify`. The second vector is a different one for every value of c. Yet the dot product is the same every time.

Comment: I realise that. But isn't it possible to define a function that would output `a[1]b[1] + a[2]b[2]` as `a.b` if `a` and `b` were already defined to be `a={a[1],a[2]}, b={b[1],b[2]}` because in most cases, that is exactly the "inverse" I am looking for. It would remove a lot of clutter in my equations, since I have vectors with >100 entries...

Comment: Dear physicslol, welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please don't post comments as answers, as it works against the Q&A and model of the site and can be unhelpful for future visitors. I've turned your answer into a proper comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple in principle, provided that you're sure you have an expression that is in fact going to simplify into a dot product:

```
Clear[a,b];
Simplify[
   (a[1] b[1] + a[2] b[2]) /. {a[1] b[1] -> 
    Dot[a, b] - a[2] b[2]}]
```

> `a.b`

Likewise for the trace:

```
Simplify[(a[1, 1] + a[2, 2]) /. {a[1, 1] -> Tr[a] - a[2, 2]}]
```

> `Tr[a]`

So you just pick one of the terms in the sum defining your compact expression, and replace that term with the compact expression minus the missing terms. Then `Simplify` will afterwards take care of the rest by canceling the individual terms. It' is however important that the compact expression doesn't contain symbols that expand to something longer again under `Simplify`. So here `a` and `b` themselves shouldn't have values assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to factor the product of a simple symbolic vector and 
some other vector, you can try this:

```
 DotFactor[expr_, v_] :=  Module[{u, res}, Drop[res, 1] /; 
   (
    res = CoefficientList[
             expr /. MapThread[Rule, {v, u^Range[Length[v]]}],
             u, 
             Length[v] + 1];
    res[[1]] == 0
    )
  ]
```

This can handle simple cases like:

```
 {a, b, c}.{x, y, z} 
 DotFactor[%, {x, y, z}]

 Out[191]= a x + b y + c z

 Out[192]= {a, b, c}
```

Or harder cases like:

```
In[298]:= 3 x + y
DotFactor[%, {x, y, z}]


Out[298]= 3 x + y

Out[299]= {3, 1, 0}
```

Or, to use your example

```
In[217]:= DotFactor[a[1] b[1] + a[2] b[2], {b[1], b[2]}] 

Out[217]= {a[1], a[2]}
```

It goes without saying that *v* should not contain anything that does not explicitly appear in the expression, e.g. {1,x,x^2} won't work as *v* unless "1" appears in the expression.