# Symbolic decomposition of a tensor given an assumption

Tags: symbolic, tensors

I am relatively new to Mathematica. Suppose I have a matrix

```
M = {{a^2, a b, 0}, {a b, b^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

How can I get Mathematica to decompose this into an outer product of the vector

```
v = {a,b,0}
```

with itself? I assume it has something to do with the function `TensorReduce` but I am not sure. In general if I know that a tensor `T` can be written in the form $T = A \otimes B$ and I know T and B how can I use mathematica to find `A`?

Related:

[Symbolic tensor simplifications and the identity matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28563/symbolic-tensor-simplifications-and-the-identity-matrix?rq=1)

[How do I simplify a vector expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21197/how-do-i-simplify-a-vector-expression)

[Simplify vector expression - is there something like "Factor" for vectors, dot products etc.?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32601/simplify-vector-expression-is-there-something-like-factor-for-vectors-dot-p)

Thank you!

Update: I think the function `CoefficientArray` may be useful here but I can't quite figure it out fully.

Comment: `With[{z = Array[x, Length@M]}, z /. Solve[M == TensorProduct[z, z], z]]`?

Comment: This works wonderfully! Now if I were to define `M = {{a c, a d, 0}, {b c, b d, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}` and I knew the form of `z` how could I use your answer to solve for `y = {c,d,0}`?

Comment: Takado,  does `With[{y = Array[x, Length@M]},  y /. Solve[M == TensorProduct[z, y], y]]` work?

Comment: Yes that exactly what I was looking for thank you :)

Comment: Takoda, I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With[{z = Array[x, Length@M]}, z /. Solve[M == TensorProduct[z, z], z]]
```

> {{-a, -b, 0}, {a, b, 0}}

**Update:** *if I were to define* `M = {{a c, a d, 0}, {b c, b d, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}` *and I knew the form of* `z` *how could I .. solve for* `y = {c,d,0}`*?*

```
M2 = {{a c, a d, 0}, {b c, b d, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
z = {a, b, 0};
With[{y = Array[x, Length@M2]}, y /. Solve[M2 == TensorProduct[z, y], y]]
```

> {{c, d, 0}}